# Database - Our system detected a lock condition in your database

Tags: magento-1.9, database

We are getting an issue with the database.

Below is the message we are getting from the server.

> Our system detected a lock condition in your database. Multiple
>   queries were running too long.

**The queries were killed to maintain your site's availability. Below is a process list of running queries for your analysis.**

[image]

Comment: What are the queries? Need to include these too.

Comment: magento1.9 sql queries

Comment: `Below is a process list of running queries for your analysis` need to see this output

Comment: @DominicXigen I have attached the image of executing queries, please check

Comment: That type query is the result of a product collection. It could literally be anything that builds a product collection like going to a category page or a cron running something which builds a product feed. If this is causing you issues it is likely that you need more resource via more expensive hosting

Comment: Hi, I am also facing this issue on my production environment so is anyone found any solution then please guide me.